# Update the values of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given some data about dishes, the location of the restaurant and its sales:

```
>>> import pandas
>>> df1 = pandas.DataFrame({"dish"     : ["fish", "chicken", "fish", "chicken", "chicken"],
...                         "location" : ["central", "central", "north", "north", "south"],
...                         "sales" : [1,3,5,2,4]})
>>> df1
      dish location  sales
0     fish  central      1
1  chicken  central      3
2     fish    north      5
3  chicken    north      2
4  chicken    south      4

>>> df2 = df1[["dish", "location"]]
>>> df2["sales_contrib"] = 0.0
>>> df2
      dish location  sales_contrib
0     fish  central            0.0
1  chicken  central            0.0
2     fish    north            0.0
3  chicken    north            0.0
4  chicken    south            0.0
```

Right now, I would like to do the following:

1. Iterate through each row of `df2`
2. Calculate the sales contrib. of that location for that dish . So for fish, **central** contributes 1/6  16.67% of total revenue and **north** contributes the remaining 83.3%

The resultant df is

```
          dish location  sales_contrib
0     fish  central            16.67
1  chicken  central            33.33
2     fish    north            83.33
3  chicken    north            22.22
4  chicken    south            44.45
```

I tried using `iteritems()` but could not get results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the power of Pandas to do this...

```
dish_totals = df1.groupby(by="dish").sum()
df2["sales_contrib"] = df1.apply((lambda row: 100*row["sales"]/dish_totals.loc[row["dish"]]), axis=1)
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
      dish location  sales_contrib
0     fish  central      16.666667
1  chicken  central      33.333333
2     fish    north      83.333333
3  chicken    north      22.222222
4  chicken    south      44.444444
```

Comment: @Vaishali Thanks... I liked your answer too because you did it without the intermediary `dish_totals` dataframe. Also, I'm not sure if it was important, but I could have rounded to two decimal places as you did.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
(df1.groupby(['dish', 'location']).sales.sum().div(df1.groupby('dish').sales.sum()) * 100).round(2).reset_index()

    dish    location    sales
0   chicken central     33.33
1   chicken north       22.22
2   chicken south       44.44
3   fish    central     16.67
4   fish    north       83.33
```